# Mass table parsing in pandas html file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to search an html file for multiple tables, (over 100) in each table if the value in cell [1,0] is "YYY" then take the value of cell [0,0] and write it to cell D"i" in an excel file, where "i" is an increasing number based on the number of entries.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\XXX.html'
table = pd.read_html(file)

wb = Workbook()

sheet1 = wb.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

i=0

filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2]

for df in table:
    comp = df.iat[1,0]

    if comp == 'YYY' :
        name = df.iat[0,0]
        print (name)
        sheet1.write(4,i, name)
        i=i+1

wb.save('MarSur.xlsx')
```

This is the error log I am getting:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/Pandas Parser/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Pandas Parser\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    comp = df.iat[1,0]
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2103, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3127, in _get_value
    return series._values[index]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: So in the first one user is `Ahmed_Abdelmuniem` and in the other it is `Ahmed`?

Comment: My bad there, I corrected the path, it produced a new error.

Comment: You probably need `iat` there instead of `at` to achieve integer-based lookup rather than label-based; see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting

Comment: I replaced 'at' with 'iat' and got the above error. Also, why would I need an integer based lookup if the value is a string "SLS"?

Comment: Then it means there is only one row in what you are trying to read from i.e. one of the dataframes... "for axis 0 with size 1" means that df has 1 row only.

Comment: Maybe `print` df's before operating on them to see if they have the content you assume?

Comment: I just printed all the data frames, and most of them have multiple rows. If a data frame only has one row, shouldn't it ignore it?

Comment: "should" is a design question. It doesn't ignore is the reality :) It is similar to `a = [9, 5]; a[2]` that gives you an error like you had. If *you* want to ignore those df's with one row, you can put an `if` in your loop; or a list comprehension to filter them e.g. `filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 1]` and loop over this one.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried the filtered table but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please share the modified code and the traceback again.

Comment: I have updated it for the code and traceback.

Comment: You should be looping over the `filtered_table`, you are not using it now! That is, change the for loop to `for df in filtered_table: ...`

Comment: It worked!!! oh man thanks!!! but one other thing, the excel file is corrupt, should I open another question for this? I want it to append the file not re-write it from scratch.

Comment: Yes, that's a different question so you better ask another one. I'm not familiar with `xlwt` library so cannot help, sorry. Good luck!

Comment: No worries, thanks a million man. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mustafa Aydin for his help,

the correct code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\XXX.html'
table = pd.read_html(file)

wb = Workbook()

sheet1 = wb.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

i=0
filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2]

for df in filtered_table:
    comp = df.iat[1,0]
#    print (comp)
    if comp == 'YYY' :
        name = df.iat[0,0]
        print (name)
        sheet1.write(4,i, name)
        i=i+1

wb.save('MarSur.xlsx')
```